# ¿como hacer que una tabla muy larga se pase a la otra página en dompdf?

Tags: php, dompdf

Buenas amigos antes que nada saludos y gracias a los que lean el comentario.

Tengo un error al generar un PDF en un sistema con Laravel usando la librería https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf pero me da un error cuando hay una tabla muy grande que debe dividirse en 2 páginas les muestro en la imágen si la tabla o una imagen es muy grande luego no me carga las siguientes paginas y me carga todo el contenido que viene en el tope de la pagina.

[image: Visual de la generación del PDF]

El código que estoy usando para generar el PDF en el controlador es el siguiente;

```html
/**
  * Generate pdf file.
  *
  * @param  int  $id
  * @return document pdf
  */
 public function pdf($id)
 {
  $document = $this->show($id);
  $body     = str_replace("\t", "", $document['body']);
  $bodyTemp = explode("\n", $body);

  // 1 - convertir las url de las imagenes en base64
  foreach($bodyTemp as $k => $v){
   if (strpos($v, '<img') !== false) {
    $img = str_replace(asset('uploads/documents/'.$document['titlefile']), "", $v);
    $img = str_replace('<img src="/', "", $img);
    $img = str_replace('"/>', "", $img);
    $imagesbase64 = Ibsa::loadImage(public_path('uploads' .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'documents' .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. $document['titlefile'] .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. $img));
    $body = str_replace(asset('uploads/documents/' . $document['titlefile'] .'/'. $img), $imagesbase64, $body);
    $document['body'] = $body;
   }
  }

  // 2 - obtener el html de la vista
  $html = view($this->selectTemplate(
   $document['front']['journal-meta']['journal-title'],
   $document['article-type'],
   'pdf'
  ))->with('d', $document)
  ->with('body',$body);

  // 3 - generar el pdf
  $pdf = PDF::loadHTML($html)->setPaper('a4', 'portrait');
        return $pdf->stream();
 }
```

y la vista con la que estoy genrando el PDF es la siguiente:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>{!! $d['front']['article-meta']['article-title'] !!}</title>
 <style>.fl{float:left}.fr{float:right}.w10{width:10%}.w20{width:20%}.w25{width:25%}.w30{width:30%}.w40{width:40%}.w50{width:50%}.w60{width:60%}.w70{width:70%}.w75{width:75%}.w80{width:80%}.w90{width:90%}.body img,.w100,table{width:100%}.text-left{text-align:left}.text-center{text-align:center}.text-right{text-align:right}.bg1{background:#F1F1F1}.bg2{background:red}.bg3{background:#00f}.bg4{background:pink}.bg5{background:#ff0}.front h1{font-size:14pt}.abstract,.authors,.trans-abstract{font-size:10pt}.aff,.cita,.doi,.history{font-size:10pt;text-align:justify}.cita,.doi,.history{padding-top:10px;word-wrap:break-word}.abstract h2,.trans-abstract h2{font-size:12pt;margin:0}.trans-abstract h2{margin-top:10px}.abstract p,.abstract strong,.trans-abstract p,.trans-abstract strong{font-size:9pt;margin:0}table{font-swize:10pt}.title{font-size:12pt;font-weight:700}.body img{max-width:700px;max-height:950px!important}.body .sec>.title{font-size:16pt;font-weight:700;border-left:2px solid #ccc;padding-left:10px}.body .sec>div>.title{font-size:14pt;font-weight:700;margin-top:10px}.body .sec>div>div>.title{font-size:13pt;font-weight:700;margin-top:10px}.body .fig{margin:10px 0}.body .fig .title{margin:0;font-weight:400!important;font-size:12pt}.ack p,.ref p{font-size:10pt}.ref p{background:#F1F1F1;padding:10px;border-left:1px solid #CCC}</style>
</head>
@php $meses = array("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"); @endphp
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <section class="front">
   <div class="w100 bg1">
    <div class="fl w70">
     <strong style="padding-right:10px;margin-right:10px;border-right:1px solid #CCCCCC;">
      {!!$d['front']['journal-meta']['journal-title']!!}
      {!!$d['front']['article-meta']['issue']!!}:
      {!!$d['front']['article-meta']['fpage']!!}-
      {!!$d['front']['article-meta']['lpage']!!}
     </strong>
     {!!$meses[$d['front']['article-meta']['pub-date']['month'] - 1]!!} - {!!$d['front']['article-meta']['pub-date']['year']!!}
    </div>
    <div class="fl w30 text-right">{!!$d['front']['article-meta']['subject']!!}</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
   </div>
   <div style="clear:both;"></div>

   <div class="w100" style="padding:15px 0 0 0;">
    <h1 class="text-center w90" style="margin:0 auto;">{!!$d['front']['article-meta']['article-title']!!}</h1>
   </div>
   <div style="clear:both;"></div>

   <div class="w100" style="padding:10px 0 0 0;">
    <h1 class="text-center w90" style="margin:0 auto;">
     {!!$d['front']['article-meta']['trans-title']!!}
    </h1>
   </div>
   <div style="clear:both;"></div>

   <div class="w100 text-center authors" style="padding:10px 0;">
    @foreach($d['front']['article-meta']['authors'] as $author)
     <span style="author text-center margin-right:15px;white-space:nowrap;">
      <nobr>
      {!!$author['surname']!!} {!! $author['given-names']!!}

      @foreach($author['xrefs'] as $xref)
       <a href="#{!!$xref['ref-rid']!!}"><sup>{!!$xref['ref-sup']!!}</sup></a>
      @endforeach

      {{-- expr --}}
      @if(isset($author['contrib-id']))
       @php
       $urlparts = parse_url($author['contrib-id']);
       $scheme   = @$urlparts['scheme'];

       if ($scheme === 'https' OR $scheme === 'http') $url = $author['contrib-id'];
       else $url = 'https://orcid.org/' . $author['contrib-id'];
       @endphp
      @endif
     
      @if($url != '')
       @php 
       $var = Ibsa::loadImage(public_path('templates' .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'template01' .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'orcid.jpg'));
       @endphp
       <a href="{!!$url!!}" target="_blank" >
        <img src="{{$var}}" alt="orcid" style="width:12px;margin-right:15px;" />
       </a>
      @endif
     </nobr>
    </span>
   @endforeach 
         
   </div>
   <div style="clear:both;"></div>

   <div class="w100">
    <table>
     <tr valign="top">
      <td style="width:120px;">
       <div class="w70">
       @php $i = 1; @endphp 
        @foreach($d['front']['article-meta']['affs'] as $aff)
        <div class="w100 aff">
         <div class="fl w10" id="'{!!$aff['label']!!}">{!!$aff['label']!!}</div>
         <div class="fl w90">{!!$aff['original']!!}<br><br></div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div> 
        @php @$i++; @endphp
          @endforeach
        @if(isset($d['front']['article-meta']['author-notes']['corresp-label']))
        <div class="w100 aff">
         <div class="fl w10" id="{!!$d['front']['article-meta']['author-notes']['corresp-label']!!}">
         @php echo $i; @endphp
         </div>
         <div class="fl w90">
          {!!$d['front']['article-meta']['author-notes']['corresp']!!}
          <br><br></div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        @endif
        
        <div class="cita">{!!$d['back']['fn-group']['fn']['p']!!}
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        <div class="history">
         @foreach($d['front']['article-meta']['history'] as $history)
          @php
           if(ucfirst($history['type']) == 'Received'): $typeHistory = 'Recibido'; 
           elseif(ucfirst($history['type']) == 'Rev-recd'): $typeHistory = 'Revisado'; 
           elseif(ucfirst($history['type']) == 'Accepted'): $typeHistory = 'Aceptado'; 
          @endphp
          @endif
          <p style="margin:0;">{{ucfirst($typeHistory)}}: 
           <span>{!!$history['day']!!} {!! $meses[$history['month'] - 1] !!} {!! $history['year'] !!}</span>
          </p>
         @endforeach
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        <div class="doi">
         DOI:
         <a href="http://dx.doi.org/{!!$d['front']['article-meta']['article-id']!!}" target="_blank">
          http://dx.doi.org/{!!$d['front']['article-meta']['article-id']!!}
         </a>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
       </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width:550px;">
       <div style="margin-left:-65px;width:93%;">
        <section class="abstract">
         <h2>{!!$d['front']['article-meta']['abstract']['title']!!}</h2>
         {!!$d['front']['article-meta']['abstract']['content']!!}
        </section>
        <section class="trans-abstract">
         <h2>{!!$d['front']['article-meta']['trans-abstract']['title']!!}</h2>{!!$d['front']['article-meta']['trans-abstract']['content']!!}
        </section>
       </div>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
   </div>
   <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </section>

  <div style="page-break-after:always;"></div>
  <section class="body">
   {!! $d['body'] !!}
  </section>

  <div style="page-break-after:always;"></div>
  <section class="back">
   <div class="col ack">
    <h2>{!! $d['back']['ack']['title'] !!}</h2>
    <p style="background:transparent;border:0;padding:0;">
    {!! $d['back']['ack']['content'] !!}</p>
   </div>

   <div class="col ref">
    <h2>{!! $d['back']['refs']['title'] !!}</h2>
    @foreach($d['back']['refs']['ref'] as $ref)
     <p id="{!! $ref['ref-id'] !!}">{!!$ref['mixed-citation']!!}</p>
    @endforeach 
   </div>
  </section>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Gracias, les agradezco de ante mano toda la ayuda que me puedan brindar en la solución del error.

Answer (score 0):

Agregándole este atributo `table{width:100%;page-break-inside: avoid;}` al CSS de la etiqueta table logré que me cargará todo el contenido bien, el asunto esta en que la tabla se corta en esa pagina y no carga todo el contenido de la tabla,

Answer (score -1):

El html debes colocarlo de esta manera:

```
    $html="<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            @page {
                margin: 0cm 0cm;
                font-family: Arial;
            }
     
            body {
                margin: 3cm 2cm 2cm;
            }
     
            header {
                 position: fixed;
                top: 30px;
                left: 0px;
                right: 80px;
                line-height: 30px;
                text-align: right;
            
            }
     
            footer {
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                right: 0px;
                text-align: center;
                line-height: 35px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>
        <img alt='PHPMailer' src='".$logo."' width='190' height='49' >
    </header>
     
    <main>
      ".$tabla."
    </main>
     
    <footer>
    </footer>
    </body>
    </html>";
```

De esta forma si es una tabla grande, se corta por pagina sin afectar el header. Para este ejemplo la tabla lo coloque aparte en otra variable llamada `$tabla` esto lo puedes adaptar a tu manera.